# "error CS0103: The name 'targetAngle' does not exist in the current context" in unity 3d while was trying to make a 3rd person camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So, I've been trying to make a third-person camera for the game I'm making in Unity 3D. I'm new to game dev(but I understand some things in this because I tried to make games earlier and tried to learn Java a bit) so I used Brackeys' guide on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE) , but every time I'm trying to compile the code, it just says that variable **targetAngle** where's stored math Atan function cannot be used in another variable **moveDir** for some reason. this is the error "Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(67,48): error CS0103: The name 'targetAngle' does not exist in the current context", and here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;


    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    public float _doubleJumpMultiplier = 1.5f;
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    private float turnSmoothVelocity;


    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask; 

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    private bool _canDoubleJump = false;
    bool _playerMove = false;


    private void Start() {

        _playerMove = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) {
            _canDoubleJump = true;
            velocity.y = -2f;

        }
         else {
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && _canDoubleJump) {
                velocity.y = 3f * _doubleJumpMultiplier;
                _canDoubleJump = false;

            }

        }

        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

if(direction.magnitude >= 0.1f) {

    float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
    float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
    

}

        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        controller.Move(moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && isGrounded && _canDoubleJump) {

            _playerMove = true;

        }  
        else
        if(!Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && isGrounded && _canDoubleJump) {

            _playerMove = false;

        } 

if(Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal") && isGrounded && _canDoubleJump) {

            _playerMove = true;

        }  
        else
        if(!Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal") && isGrounded && _canDoubleJump) {

            _playerMove = false;

        }



        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `targetAngle` in this if statement:

```
if(direction.magnitude >= 0.1f) {

    float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
    float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
    

}
```

And attempt to use it outside of it in the following line. But here `targetAngle` is out of scope.

```
        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
```